# Euler numbers and permanent of matrices

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, matrices, permanent

Motivated by [Question 402249](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402249) of [Zhi-Wei Sun](https://mathoverflow.net/users/124654/zhi-wei-sun), I consider  the permanent of matrices

$$e(n)=\mathrm{per}\left[\operatorname{sgn} \left(\tan\pi\frac{j+k}n \right)\right]_{1\le j,k\le n-1},$$
where $n$ is an odd integer greater than 1 and $ \operatorname{sgn} $ is the sign-function.

When $n=3,5,7,$ the matrices are
$$\left[ \begin {array}{cc} -1&0\\ 0&1\end {array}
 \right] ,
$$

$$
\left[ \begin {array}{cccc} 1&-1&-1&0\\ -1&-1&0&1
\\ -1&0&1&1\\ 0&1&1&-1\end {array}
 \right], 
$$

$$
\left[ \begin {array}{cccccc} 1&1&-1&-1&-1&0\\ 1&-1
&-1&-1&0&1\\ -1&-1&-1&0&1&1\\ -1&-
1&0&1&1&1\\ -1&0&1&1&1&-1\\ 0&1&1&
1&-1&-1\end {array} \right].
$$

Numerical computation indicates that

$$e(n)=E(n-1)$$

for $3 \leq n \leq 23 $, where $E(n)$ are the [Euler numbers](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Euler_numbers).

```
                 [e(3) = -1, E(2) = -1]

                  [e(5) = 5, E(4) = 5]

                [e(7) = -61, E(6) = -61]

               [e(9) = 1385, E(8) = 1385]

            [e(11) = -50521, E(10) = -50521]

           [e(13) = 2702765, E(12) = 2702765]

        [e(15) = -199360981, E(14) = -199360981]

       [e(17) = 19391512145, E(16) = 19391512145]

    [e(19) = -2404879675441, E(18) = -2404879675441]

   [e(21) = 370371188237525, E(20) = 370371188237525]

[e(23) = -69348874393137901, E(22) = -69348874393137901]
```

**Conjecture.** For any odd integer $n>1$, $e(n)=E(n-1)$.

**Question 1.** How to prove this conjecture?

---

**Edit.**

By [T. Amdeberhan's recent MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402596),

$$\mathrm{det}\left[\operatorname{sgn} \left(\tan\pi\frac{j+k}n \right)\right]_{1\le j,k\le n-1}=(-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}=\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})\neq 0,$$

we can consider the permanent of inverse matrices

$$e'(n)=\mathrm{per}(A^{-1}),$$

where $A=\left[\operatorname{sgn} \left(\tan\pi\frac{j+k}n \right)\right]_{1\le j,k\le n-1}$ and $n$ is an odd integer greater than 1.

When $n=3,5,7,$ $A^{-1}$ equals

$$\left[ \begin {array}{cc} -1&0\\ 0&1\end {array}
 \right], 
$$

$$
\left[ \begin {array}{cccc} 1&-1&1&0\\ -1&-1&0&-1
\\ 1&0&1&1\\ 0&-1&1&-1\end {array}
 \right], 
$$
$$
\left[ \begin {array}{cccccc} 1&1&-1&1&1&0\\  1&-1&-
1&1&0&-1\\  -1&-1&-1&0&-1&-1\\  1&1&0
&1&1&1\\  1&0&-1&1&1&-1\\  0&-1&-1&1
&-1&-1\end {array} \right] 
$$
respectively.

Numerical computation indicates that all elements of $A^{-1}$ are $-1, 0, 1 $ and

$$e'(n)=E(n-1)$$

for $3 \leq n \leq 23 $.

**Added Conjecture 1.** For any odd integer $n>1$, $e'(n)=E(n-1)$.

The following are some properties of the $A$  and $A^{-1}$ that may be easy to prove:

**Added Conjecture 2.** For any odd integer $n>1$, all elements of $A^{-1}$ are $-1, 0, 1 $.

**Added Conjecture 3.** For any odd integer $n>1$,  the Characteristic Polynomials of $A$ and $A^{-1}$ are
$$
\mathrm{Char}(A)=\mathrm{Char}(A^{-1})={\frac { \left( \lambda+i \right) ^{n-1} + \left( \lambda-i \right) ^{n-1}}{2}},
$$
where $i^2=-1$ and $\mathrm{Char}(A)=\mathrm{det}(\lambda I-A)$.

**Question 2.** How to prove these added conjectures?

---

**Edit.**

**The connection between  characteristic polynomials and  recurrences of Euler numbers:**

Let

$$\mathrm{Char}(A)|_{\lambda=iE}=\mathrm{det}(\lambda I-A)|_{\lambda=iE}={\frac { \left( iE+i \right) ^{n-1} + \left( iE-i \right) ^{n-1}}{2}}=0,$$

we deduce

$$(E+1)^{n-1}+(E-1)^{n-1}=0,$$

which is [the recurrence formula for the Euler numbers](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Euler_numbers) ($E^n≡E_n≡E(n)$ in symbolic notation).

**Question 3.** Is this a coincidence?

---

**Edit.**

Let $B=\left[\operatorname{sgn} \left(\sin\pi\frac{j+k}n \right)\right]_{1\le j,k\le n-1}$ where $n>1$  is an integer.

[Zhi-Wei Sun](https://mathoverflow.net/users/124654/zhi-wei-sun) and [Nemo](https://mathoverflow.net/users/82588/nemo) guessed in the comments that

$$\mathrm{per}(B)=E(n-1)$$
for any integer $n>1$.

Numerical calculations show that this is correct for $1<n\leq 23$.

It is easy to see that $\mathrm{det}(B)=0$ for any even number $n$ and it seems that
$$\mathrm{det}(B)=\mathrm{det}(A)=(-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\neq 0$$
for any odd integer $n>1$.

When $n=3,5,7,$ $B$ and $B^{-1}$ are equal to

$$\left[ \begin {array}{cc} 1&0\\ 0&-1\end {array}
 \right] , \left[ \begin {array}{cc} 1&0\\ 0&-1
\end {array} \right] ,$$

$$ \left[ \begin {array}{cccc} 1&1&1&0\\ 1&1&0&-1
\\ 1&0&-1&-1\\ 0&-1&-1&-1
\end {array} \right] , \left[ \begin {array}{cccc} 1&-1&1&0
\\ -1&1&0&-1\\ 1&0&-1&1
\\ 0&-1&1&-1\end {array} \right] ,$$

$$ 
\left[ \begin {array}{cccccc} 1&1&1&1&1&0\\ 1&1&1&
1&0&-1\\ 1&1&1&0&-1&-1\\ 1&1&0&-1&
-1&-1\\ 1&0&-1&-1&-1&-1\\ 0&-1&-1&
-1&-1&-1\end {array} \right] , \left[ \begin {array}{cccccc} 1&-1&1&-1
&1&0\\ -1&1&-1&1&0&-1\\ 1&-1&1&0&-1&1\\ -1&1&0&-1&1&-1\\ 1&0&-1&1&-1
&1\\ 0&-1&1&-1&1&-1\end {array} \right] 
$$
respectively.

A natural question is: Does $B$ and $B^{-1}$ have the same properties as $A$ and $A^{-1}$ for any odd integer $n>1$.

**Added Conjecture 4.** For any odd integer $n>1$,
$$\mathrm{per}(B)=\mathrm{per}(B^{-1})=E(n-1)$$ and  $$
\mathrm{Char}(B)=\mathrm{Char}(B^{-1})={\frac { \left( \lambda+i \right) ^{n-1} + \left( \lambda-i \right) ^{n-1}}{2}}.
$$

**Question 4.** If  $$\mathrm{per}(C)=\mathrm{per}(C^{-1})=E(n-1)$$
and
$$\mathrm{Char}(C)=\mathrm{Char}(C^{-1})={\frac { \left( \lambda+i \right) ^{n-1} + \left( \lambda-i \right) ^{n-1}}{2}},$$
where $n$ is an odd number greater than $1,$ $C$ is an $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ matrix and all elements of $C$ are $-1, 0, 1 ,$ what can we say about $C$?

Comment: So equivalently, the matrix is: $\frac{n - 3}{2}$ antidiagonals of 1s, $\frac{n - 1}{2}$ antidiagonals of -1s, an antidiagonal of $0$s, $\frac{n - 1}{2}$ antidiagonals of 1s, and $\frac{n - 3}{2}$ antidiagonals of -1s, in that order. Right?

Comment: @user44191 Yes, the matrix is equivalent to it.

Comment: In contrast, I observe that $$\det\left[\mathrm{sgn}\left(\tan\pi\frac{j+k}{2n+1}\right)\right]_{1\le j,k\le 2n}=(-1)^n.$$

Comment: I guess we also have $$\mathrm{per}\left[\mathrm{sgn}\left(\sin\pi\frac{j+k}{n+1}\right)\right]_{1\le j,k\le n}=E_{n}$$ and $$(-1)^n\frac{4(n+1)}{(2n+1)!!}\mathrm{per}\left[\sin\pi\frac{j+k}{2n+1}\right]_{1\le j,k\le 2n}\in\{1,2,3,\ldots\}.$$

Comment: @ Zhi-Wei Sun  When $n=7$, $$(-1)^n\frac{4(n+1)}{(2n+1)!!}\mathrm{per}\left[\sin\pi\frac{j+k}{2n+1}\right]_{1\le j,k\le 2n}=157.5 \not \in\{1,2,3,\ldots\} $$

Comment: @Zhi-WeiSun: see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402596/determinants-of-striped-hankel-matrices, I think it is the same as what you mentioned.

Comment: Here's a naive/obvious comment: Euler numbers (up to sign) count alternating permutations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_permutation); the terms of the permanent correspond to permutations; perhaps one can define a sign-reversing involution on these terms, so that only the terms corresponding to alternating permutations survive (and all such terms have the same sign).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conjecture and the added Conjectures 1 and 2 have been proved.
See the preprint *Proof of five conjectures relating permanents to combinatorial sequences* by Fu, Lin and me available from http://arXiv.org/abs/2109.11506.

Answer (score 10):

When interpreted using permutations, the conjecture "$\mathrm{per}(B)=E(n-1)$ for any integer $n>1$" is a known fact, often attributed to Roselle [3]. More precisely, when we view $\mathrm{per}(B)$ as the sum over signed permutation matrices, where the "sign" tells us whether the concerned entry is an excedance (-1), a drop (+1), or a fixed point (0), the identity for $\mathrm{per}(B)$ is equivalent to the following one:

$$\sum_{\sigma\in D_{2n}}(-1)^{\mathrm{exc}(\sigma)}=(-1)^nE_{2n}, \; n\ge 0.$$

Here $E_{2n}$ is the secant number as in $\mathrm{sec}(t)=\sum_{n\ge 0}E_{2n}t^{2n}/(2n)!$. See also [1,2,4] for various proofs of a q-analog of the above result.

[1] D. Foata, G.-N. Han, The q-tangent and q-secant numbers via basic eulerian polynomials, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 138 (2) (2010) 385–393.

[2] M. Josuat-Vergès, A q-enumeration of alternating permutations, European J. Combin. (2010), no. 7, 1892–1906.

[3] D.P. Roselle, Permutations by number of rises and successions, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 19 (1968) 8–16.

[4] H. Shin, J. Zeng, The q-tangent and q-secant numbers via continued fractions, Eur. J. Comb. 31 (7) (2010) 1689–1705.

Comment: When $n=3$,  $$\det(1-XA^T)=-x_{{1}}x_{{2}}+x_{{1}}-x_{{2}}+1 \neq \det(1-XB^T)=-x_{{1}}x_{{2}}-x_{{1}}+x_{{2}}+1.$$

Comment: @Shishuo Fu  Is there a similar way to prove that $$\mathrm{per}(A)=\mathrm{per}(A^{-1})=\mathrm{per}(B^{-1})=E(n-1)$$ for any odd integer $n>1$?

Comment: @Deyi Chen For the other three matrics $A$, $A^{-1}$, and $B^{-1}$, we can similarly interprete their permanents as signed summations over derangements, but now the permutation statistics involved are not familiar ones such as the number of exceedances. So results analogous to that of Roselle have not been found yet, at least not that I know of. Nonetheless, this does raise interesting combinatorial questions on these permutation statistics.

Comment: @Deyi Chen I know how to prove that $\mathrm{per}(B^{-1})=E(n-1)$ now, using a variant of the statistic $\mathrm{exc}$, defined according to the pattern of $B^{-1}$. Still no clue for $A$ and $A^{-1}$ though.

Comment: @Shishuo Fu I am glad to hear that you proved $\mathrm{per}(B^{-1})=E(n-1)$, it's an  interesting result !