# Permanents and Kummer-like congruence

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, permanent

Recently, several of my conjectures in [Question 402572](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402572) and [Question 403336](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403336/) were proved by Fu, Lin and Sun available from [Proofs of five conjectures relating permanents to combinatorial sequences](http://arXiv.org/abs/2109.11506).

These questions relate to the permanents of matrices
$$\left[\operatorname{sgn} \left(\sin\pi\frac{j+k}{n+1} \right)\right]_{1\le j,k\le n}, \left[\operatorname{sgn} \left(\sin\pi\frac{j+2k}{n+1} \right)\right]_{1\le j,k\le n} , \left[\operatorname{sgn} \left(\tan\pi\frac{j+k}{2n+1} \right)\right]_{1\le j,k\le 2n}.$$

It seems natural to ask: what is the value of $\mathrm{per}(A)$ where
$$A=\left[\operatorname{sgn} \left(\cos\pi\frac{j+k}{n+1} \right)\right]_{1\le j,k\le n}.$$

When $n=1,2,3,4,5,6,$  $A=$
$$\left[ \begin {array}{c} -1\end {array} \right] ,$$

$$\left[ \begin {array}{cc} -1&-1\\ -1&-1\end {array}
 \right],$$

$$\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 0&-1&-1\\ -1&-1&-1
\\ -1&-1&0\end {array} \right] ,$$

$$\left[ \begin {array}{cccc} 1&-1&-1&-1\\ -1&-1&-1&-
1\\ -1&-1&-1&-1\\ -1&-1&-1&1
\end {array} \right] ,$$

$$\left[ \begin {array}{ccccc} 1&0&-1&-1&-1\\ 0&-1&-1
&-1&-1\\ -1&-1&-1&-1&-1\\ -1&-1&-1
&-1&0\\ -1&-1&-1&0&1\end {array} \right] ,$$

$$\left[ \begin {array}{cccccc} 1&1&-1&-1&-1&-1\\ 1&-
1&-1&-1&-1&-1\\ -1&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1
\\ -1&-1&-1&-1&-1&-1\\ -1&-1&-1&-1
&-1&1\\ -1&-1&-1&-1&1&1\end {array} \right]$$
respectively.

**Deﬁnition.** Given a sequence $\{a_k\}$, deﬁne a new sequence $\{b_m\}$ by

$$b_m=T_m(a_k)=\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{m}{k}a_k.$$

The sequence $\{b_m\}$  is the binomial transform of $\{a_k\}$.

Let $E_n$ satisfy
$$\sec{x}+\tan{x}=\sum_{n\geq 0}E_n\frac{x^n}{n!}=1+1\frac{x}{1!}+1\frac{x^2}{2!}+2\frac{x^3}{3!}+5\frac{x^4}{4!}+16\frac{x^5}{5!}+61\frac{x^6}{6!}+272\frac{x^7}{7!}+1385\frac{x^8}{8!}+7936\frac{x^9}{9!}+\cdots$$

The  binomial transform of $\{E_{2k+1}\}$ and $\{E_{2k}\}$ are
$$T_m(E_{2k+1})=\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{m}{k}E_{2k+1}$$
and
$$T_m(E_{2k})=\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{m}{k}E_{2k}$$
respectively.

We have the following

**Conjecture 1.**  For any positive integer $n$,

\begin{align}
   \mathrm{per}(A)&=
   \begin{cases}
   -T_m(E_{2k+1})&\mbox{if $n=2m+1$ }\\
   T_m(E_{2k})&\mbox{if $n=2m$ }
   \end{cases}.
  \end{align}

Numerical computation indicates that it is true for $1≤n≤21$.

```
per(A)= -1, 2, -3, 8, -21, 80, -327, 1664, -9129, 58112, -396363, 3027968, -24615741, 219392000, -2068052367, 21065007104, -225742096209, 2586813857792, -31048132997523, 395317106966528, -5252064083753061.
```

Denote $a(n)=\mathrm{per}(A)$.

Motivated by [Question 404530](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404530), especially [Daniel Barsky's congruence](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Eslc/opapers/s05barsky.html) for Fubini numbers, I discovered the following interesting arithmetic properties of $a(n)$

**Conjecture 2.**  For any prime $p$ and positive integer $n>1$,
$$a(n) \equiv a(n+2p-2) \pmod p.$$

**Conjecture 3.**  For any prime $p$,
$$a(2p) \equiv 2 \pmod p.$$
**Proof (Suppose Conjecture 1 holds).**

Noting $E_{2p}\equiv 1\pmod p$ [1], we have
$$a(2p) =T_p(E_{2k})= \sum_{k=0}^{p}\binom{p}{k}E_{2k}\equiv 1+E_{2p} \equiv 2\pmod p.$$

Moreover

**Conjecture 4.** For any prime $p$ and positive integer $n>h≥1$,
$$a(n) \equiv a(n+2(p-1)p^{h-1}) \pmod{p^h}.$$

By [1], this is a Kummer-like congruence. I believe that for some "nice matrices" $B_n$, $b(n)=\mathrm{per}(B_n)$ will have a Kummer-like congruence, e.g. matrices in  [Question 402572](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402572), [Question 403336](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403336/) (c.f. [1]) and [Question 404530](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404530). This can be used to discover new congruences.

**Question.** Are these results correct? How to prove them?

[1] Donald E. Knuth and Thomas J. Buckholtz, Computation of tangent, Euler and Bernoulli numbers, Math. Comp. 21 1967 663-688.

Answer (score 2):

In Conjecture 1 for even $n$, we have a matrix of all $-1$'s overlapped with two triangles of $1$'s with length $m-1$ (for $m:=\frac{n}2$) at the corners, which are located on distinct rows/columns.

Noticing that the rook polynomial for such a triangle is given by
$$\sum_{i=0}^m S(m,m-i) x^i,$$
where $S(\cdot,\cdot)$ are Stirling numbers of second kind, and using inclusion-exclusion, we get the formula
$$\operatorname{per}(A) = \sum_{i=0}^m \sum_{j=0}^m S(m,m-i)S(m,m-j)(-2)^{i+j}(n-i-j)!.$$

Comment: It seems that the paper available from https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82350429.pdf may be useful. Is there a more natural (or similar) way to prove the problems in Question 402572 and Question 403336 ?

Comment: And formula (4) in  https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.5358 may be useful.